# Clicking anything in Firefox 5 triggers two panels to appear

Tags: windows-7, firefox

When I installed Firefox it was working fine. Since yesterday it has been behaving very odd.

When I right-click or left click on any link/option, like the menu bar, it shows two panels as captured in the picture below.

[image: firefox with mystery jack panels]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any Add-Ons installed?

Comment: Yes I installed. But the same Add-Ons extension didn't give any problem before.

Comment: I tried to disable it but still the same result.

Comment: What happens when you launch Firefox in Safe Mode?

Comment: It's very strange to me know that there is no safe mode in this version.   :-(

Comment: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Basic%20Troubleshooting#w_4-restart-firefox-in-safe-mode

Comment: Doesn't help either in safe mode neither re-install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme was not supporting the Firefox that was the reason. After changing the theme I could fix this problem. Thank you @Windos for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try a full uninstall. After running the wizard make sure to clean out `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` in case anything is left behind.

For good measure also search the registry for "firefox" and check our profile's AppData for any FireFox entries.

Once all this is done then try a fresh install, to be on the safe side download the installer from Mozilla again... there may well have been an update and it will rule out possible corruption.

Comment: I've done uninstall and now I'm waiting for my next reboot and then I'll install it again and then I'll respond you.

Comment: It doesn't work.